# Displaying rich content with images, videos and text. custom solution or webview?

Tags: android, parse-platform, webview

I can't deside what is the best approach for an **Android** App i'm building on a **Parse** server.
In this app i will have a lot of content that will be like **blog posts**, with many **images**, **videos** and **text**.
I was thinking of creating a layout with code and add all those content elements on the fly from the **ParsePlatform** database.

I can also have those post on a wordpres site and show them with a **webview**

Is webview a better approach? Those are my concerns:

- I guess parse is way faster than a blog website.
- If the website for some reason stop working the app will have **null
  content**. if the parse database has a problem the user might not be
  able to login.

What is the best and correct approach? i feel that webview is not a good idea. how other big applications with rich content in many screens does this?

Answer (score 0):

If it's heavily rich, and seems like a web page, I think it's best to use a web page.

If you choose it, consider optimizing and making it look fine on mobile. Maybe even make it have material design, if possible.

Choosing webView has its own disadvantages, but you get a viewer out of the box, without a lot of messing around with parsing and possible memory issues.